# Disabling the behaviour of iOS when pressing buttons with :hover states

Tags: jquery, html, css, ios, hover

So often I click on buttons on sites when using my iPad and what iOS does is it actually toggles the :hover state that the designer created, which was only ever meant to be an actual :hover event. I have made a website which is suffering from this pretty pointless behaviour. 
For example, you can click on a button that doesn't leave the page, but in iOS, it would show the hover state of that button permanently.
How can one elegantly remove this ill thought out behaviour
?

Answer (score 0):

By adding new CSS files and using conditional comments for max-width devices, and then resetting the hover state in these new css files for example...

iPhone

```
    <link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" href="css/iphone.css" type="text/css" title="no title"/>
```

iPad

```
    <link media="only screen and (device-width: 768px)" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ipad.css" type="text/css" title="no title"/>
```

Then just tweak what css gets outputted for these devices.

Answer (score 0):

This will require some javascript but this is the best solution I could come up with.

Basically you will override the default styles then toggle a class instead of relying on the hover event.

I'd say this solution is pretty simple and allows the user to both be able to click the top level link and expand/collapse the link

**The HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="some-url">link name <span></span></a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="some-url">link name</a></li>
       </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="some-url">link name <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="some-url">link name <span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS**

```
li{width:200px;}

li a span{
    display:inline-block;
    height:10px;
    width:10px; 
    background:#000;
    float:right;
}
/* Standard menu system */
li ul{display:none}
li:hover ul {display:block}


/* Override for ios */
/* Needs to be inside some media query */
/* Something like @media(max-width:497px) */

li:hover ul{display:none;}

li.hovered ul{display:block}
```

**The Javascript (jquery)**

```
    $('nav li a span').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('nav li').not($(e.target).parents('li')).removeClass('hovered');
        $(e.target).parent('a').parent('li').toggleClass('hovered');
    })
```

**Working JsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/styks1987/DY6kS/2/